# Why am I receiving end-of-file error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

In Oracle, I keep getting the PLS-00103 error (encountered symbol "end-of-file")
I have played around with the ; and to no avail have I found a solution. Anybody
know what might be wrong with my code snippet? (Error is at line 6)

```
    1  Create or Replace Trigger TaxGeneration
    2  After Insert on Pay_records
    3  For each row
    4  DECLARE
    5  tax number;
    6  BEGIN
    7  number := new.Netsalary%type;
    8  dbms_output.put_line(number);
    9  END
    /
```

Comment: I don't think use can use `new.Netalary%type`. I think you'll need to change that to `PAY_RECORDS.NETSALARY%TYPE`. (Note that capitalization isn't really important, but since Oracle defaults to upper case I do too :-).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the ; on END;

END always needs a ;

You also can't name a variable "number", that's a reserved Oracle keyword. Try new_number (or something else) instead and see if it works.

Also, remove the "%type". That's not necessary here.

```
Create or Replace Trigger TaxGeneration
After Insert on Pay_records
For each row
DECLARE
tax number;
BEGIN
    tax := :new.Netsalary;
    dbms_output.put_line(tax);
END;
```

Comment: Fixed that error, but now I have an error at line 1 stating that it is an invalid SQL statement (ORA-00900). Removed the or replace part, still the same

Comment: I added another comment as to what I see wrong, check again.

Comment: Did not have a noticeable effect on the trigger. Right now it is complaining about line 4 (DECLARE). "PL/SQL: Statement ignored"

Comment: There's one minor mistake remaining - you have to use `:new` instead of `new`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable name is "tax", "number" it's the type of tax variable.

try  "tax := new.Netsalary%type;"
     "dbms_output.put_line(tax);"

Comment: Did not see that, helped a bit, thanks! Still have error though (ORA-00900 now)

Answer (score 0):

`number := new.Netsalary%type;`

Should be

```
tax := :new.Netsalary; --considering tax is the correct variable to be used
```

`number` is a data type and cannot be used as a variable name.

`%type` is an attribute that let's you copy the data type of a field, record, nested table, database column, or variable in your own declarations. For e.g. you don't know (or are too lazy to find out) the data type of column `tax` in table `salary` and you want your variable `l_tax` to be the same data type as column `tax`, you'd simply declare `l_tax salary.tax%TYPE;`.

---

`END
/`

Should be

`END;
/`

The `END;` signifies the end of your PLSQL block and the `/` tells SQL*Plus to execute the PLSQL Block.